# Flutter Navigator and Routing in separate files showing error: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/details", null) in the _Widget

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I am working on this Flutter app and trying to make routing works on separate files. Now I have a login page, and in it, there is a login button. When this login button is clicked, the app should navigate to the HomePage. I looked at a few tutorials, but they all put navigators and other widgets on the same page.

In my case, my file structure is:

[image: project file structure in lib]

and in routes.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'widgets/login.dart';
import 'widgets/homepage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Nav2App());
}

class Nav2App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => Login(),
        '/homepage': (context) => HomePage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In login.dart:

```
child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              ...
              ))),
          child: const Text('Login'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/homepage',
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

I think I need to do something in main.dart, like:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Login Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyLoginPage(title: 'login page'),
      routes: ***something***
    );
  }
```

Comment: I just found out that when I copied my code from my editor, I made a mistake. I have updated my question. Sorry for the confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to replace the login page with the homepage. So use push replacement. That way they won’t get a back button in the top left.

As you said you updated the /details to /homepage in the comments above. But still not working make sure you do a full reload not just a hot reload.

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/homepage");
```

Do **not** make a second material app in your  your code like shows above. When you create another material app you also get a whole new navigator stack.

Use Scaffold instead. 1 material app is all you need.

Comment: You are right about the 1 material app rule. It turns out I made a few other mistakes other than navigation. Now I fixed them. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
   class Nav2App extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
         initialRoute: '/',
          routes: {
            '/': (context) => Login(),
            '/homepage': (context) => HomePage(),
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: yep, the '/details' should be '/homepage', it's a typo when I copying my code to StackOverflow. In my local editor, I have '/homepage' navigator in the ```onPressed``` function. I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: add initialRoute to your materialApp()

Answer (score 0):

There is no navigator for your `/details` name.

Change your login code like below:

```
child: TextButton(
          style: ButtonStyle(
              ...
              ))),
          child: const Text('Login'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              '/homepage',
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: yep, the '/details' should be '/homepage', it's a typo when I copying my code to StackOverflow. In my local editor, I have '/homepage' navigator in the ```onPressed``` function. I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.